# async wait in Speech recognizer

Tags: c#, async-await, speech-recognition

I'm trying duplicating [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378426(v=office.14).aspx) example with the following changes:

1. Using Console app instead of Windows: This looks to be fine as the computer is speaking to me
2. Using `Sync` functionality: and here looks I've a mistake.

**UPDATE**
Once the program is executed, it speaks to me, and waited for key to be pressed, after that it waited a little to 'listening' but the `sre_SpeechRecognized` is not executed.

Below is my code, thanks:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

class Startup {
        // Create a simple handler for the SpeechRecognized event
    static void sre_SpeechRecognized (object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string speech = e.Result.Text;

                //handle custom commands
        switch (speech)
        {
            case "red":
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                break;
            case "green":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad");
                break;
            case "blue":
                Console.WriteLine("You said blue");
                break;
            case "Close":
               Console.WriteLine("Speech recognized: {0}", e.Result.Text);
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Speech recognized: {0}", e.Result.Text);
    }

public async Task<object> Invoke(dynamic i) {
// Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        // Configure the audio output. 
        synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // Speak a string.
        synth.Speak("This example demonstrates a basic use of Speech Synthesizer");

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Create a new SpeechRecognitionEngine instance.
        SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

        // Create a simple grammar that recognizes "red", "green", or "blue".
        Choices colors = new Choices();
        colors.Add(new string[] { "red", "green", "blue" });

        // Create a GrammarBuilder object and append the Choices object.
        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(colors);

        // Create the Grammar instance and load it into the speech recognition engine.
        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
        recognizer.LoadGrammar(g);

        // Register a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
        recognizer.SpeechRecognized += 
          new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs> (Startup.sre_SpeechRecognized);
       Console.WriteLine("Exiting now..");
   return null;
}
}
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Where's `Await` in the `Async` method

Comment: I updated my question to elaborate more the issue, thanks

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I do not know where shall I use the `await` in this example, can you advise

Comment: All the `Async` methods, need `Await`, else they are `Sync`, but I think you need `TaskCompletionSource`, instead of Async Await to ensure you can wrap Event using Task API

Comment: @MrinalKamboj can you help with some code lines, I'm new to c# in general, thanks

Comment: I can try something, but your `Invoke` method makes no sense for me, you are assigning the event and exiting, so it will never fire the event, as `SpeechRecognizer` object cease to exist

Comment: @MrinalKamboj the `Invoke` method I used is almost 99% copy from the MSDN site I pointed to. thansk

Comment: Check now, I have modified result to `Task<string>`, but you may change it to Task<object> it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `Invoke` method as follows (this is typical case of `Async` caller (Node Js here) waiting for a `Synchronous` event to complete)

**Important Details** (please note basis of this modification is that otherwise Speech engine is working as expected)

1. Made Invoke method Sync, instead of Async, as there was no Async call in the original code
2. Replaced the return value as Task to fetch the event return value
3. Made the event Inline for ease of using objects
4. Added `Recognize` sync method in the end
5. Will return when the Task completes post event firing and will contain result inside `Task<string>`, which can fetch result using `TaskObject.Result` property

   ```
     public async Task<object> Invoke(dynamic i) {    // async here is required to be used by Edge.JS that is a node.js module enable communicating with C# files
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
     // Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
       SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

       // Configure the audio output. 
       synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

       // Speak a string.
       synth.Speak("This example demonstrates a basic use of Speech Synthesizer");

       Console.WriteLine();
       Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
       Console.ReadKey();

       // Create a new SpeechRecognitionEngine instance.

       SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

       recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

       // Create a simple grammar that recognizes "red", "green", or "blue".
       Choices colors = new Choices();
       colors.Add(new string[] { "red", "green", "blue" });

       // Create a GrammarBuilder object and append the Choices object.
       GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
       gb.Append(colors);

       // Create the Grammar instance and load it into the speech recognition engine.
       Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
       recognizer.LoadGrammar(g);

       // Register a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
       recognizer.SpeechRecognized += (sender,e) => {

          string speech = e.Result.Text;

           //handle custom commands
           switch (speech)
           {
               case "red":
                tcs.SetResult("Hello Red");
               break;
               case "green":
                tcs.SetResult("Hello Green");
               break;
               case "blue":
                tcs.SetResult("Hello Blue");
                break;
               case "Close":
                tcs.SetResult("Hello Close");
               break;
              default:
                tcs.SetResult("Hello Not Sure");
             break;
   }

    };

      // For Edge JS we cannot await an Async Call (else it leads to error)
      recognizer.Recognize();              
      return tcs.Task.Result;

      //// For pure C#
      // await recognizer.RecognizeAsync();              
      // return tcs.Task;
   }
   ```

**Async specific changes**

1. `public async Task<object> Invoke(dynamic i)` (Make method `async` and return type `Task`, requirements of an async method)
2. Call `await recognizer.RecognizeAsync();` (Call await on Async call)
3. `return tcs.Task` (return type needs to be Task)

Comment: Thanks, I slightly tuned your code, it is fine, now I've to look how to make it stable.

Comment: Sure, glad it can help, let me know if something blocks, but the essence is to serve the use case defined by you

Comment: Regarding the Edit suggested, API changes are fine, but why do want method to be marked `async`, without `await`, its of literally no use and also if you are returning `Task.Result`, then change the return type to `object` instead of `Task<object>`, pure `synchronous` method, here biggest challenge is you do not understand the working of `async-await`. I will accept edit with few improvements.

Comment: Also in case you are too keen to use `async` in the method, then check the latest Edit (at bottom)

Comment: mm, I like to accept your answer, but actually for my case, where I'm using `edge.js` I have to use `public async Task<object> Invoke(dynamic i)` and can not use `await recognizer.RecognizeAsync();` as the `node.js` execution give me error

Comment: Alright, then suggest an edit again I will accept for your specific requirement, since I am talking purely from C# perspective, so we have a gap in our understanding. Then you may accept and Up-Vote, if it is useful

Comment: I have modified the edit to change only the C# part, `Edge JS` remains intact as expected

Answer (score 1):

You don't start the recognition. Please see the link you posted. There is a line `sre.Recognize();` (which is missing in your code) after registering the event in the example. There is also a method `RecognizeAsync()` mentioned, which might be what you want.

Comment: Good catch, certainly event is not invoked, but that may not solve the issue for an `Async` method, especially if a return is expected from the Invoke method, as event has `void` Return

Comment: Just added it, did not work :(, I even tried both `sre.Recognize();` and sre.RecognizeAsync();

Comment: Pleas show code where `Invoke` is called and also try to debug the event to understand how does it gets fired, what does `SpeechRecognizer` understands

Comment: Point remains, I am not sure how are you calling Invoke method in first place, also is using `Async`, please use `Await` alongwith to free up the calling thread

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I'm calling it through nodejs, using Edje.js module, as I mentioned the `speek` is fine, but the `listen` is not working, the Edje.js is calling the `Invoke`.